# Remove space between inline clip-path divs

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I've made three inline divs, each with an image and caption. Both the caption and image use css clip-path property. The image and the caption is wrapped in 
`.gallery-inner` class. The code is working fine, but I would like keep no empty spaces between these divs.

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qw0z3um/2/)

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="gallery-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800" class="img-responsive img-slant--1">
        <div class="caption red">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800" class="img-responsive img-slant--2">
        <div class="caption blue">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-inner">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800" class="img-responsive img-slant--3">
        <div class="caption orange">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
.img-slant--1{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.img-slant--2{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.img-slant--3{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(20% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.gallery-inner{
    position: relative;
    width: 33.333333%;
    float: left;
}
.gallery-inner img{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.caption {
    width: 100%;
}
.red{
    background-color: #a31d22;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 1%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
.blue{
    background-color: #33658a;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 80% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
}
.orange{
    background-color: #ca5a27;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 20% 100%);
}
h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Is there any way I can remove the space between `.gallery-inner`?

An image will help to understand what I want. Here is the example image:

[image: Test]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this below .gallery in your CSS file:

```
.gallery-inner:nth-child(2){
  transform: translateX(-75px);
}

.gallery-inner:nth-child(3){
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}
```

I hope it helps. I'm sure it works.